# How to send JSON data in Axios post request?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, post, axios

I want to send this as a request data in my axios post request. How can I do that?
`

```
{
        "userName": "arijitdas10101",
        "userPassword":"arijit",
        "firstName": "arijit2",
        "lastName": "das",
        "phone": "1234567891",
        "email": "das@gmail.com",
        "aadharNo": "123456789112",
        "addressDTO":
            {
                "streetName": "14/1 west",
                "city":"Delhi",
                "state":"WB",
                "pinCode": 70012166
            }
}
```

Here is how I tried to send it ...
It's giving an HTTP status code of 400. Please help me with this

```
export const register = (userName,userPassword,firstName,lastName,phone,email,aadharNo,streetName,city,state,pincode) => async (dispatch) => {

try{
    dispatch({
        type:USER_REGISTER_REQUEST
    })
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        };
        const addressDTO={streetName,city,state,pincode}
    const {responseData} = await axios.post(`http://localhost:6969/v1/api/createCustomer`,{userName,userPassword,firstName,lastName,phone,email,aadharNo,addressDTO},config)
    console.log(responseData);
    dispatch({
        type:USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload:data
    })
}catch(error){
    dispatch({
        type:USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload:error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
}
}
```

Comment: @DreamBold can u explain a bit please with code?

Comment: @DreamBold its a post request with axios

Comment: So it should be: `const {responseData} = await axios.post('http://localhost:6969/v1/api/createCustomer', {data: your_JSON_data}, config)` Please try that and let me know

Comment: Are you asking how to make the JSON data from the input `export const register = (userName,userPassword,firstName,lastName, phone, email, aadharNo, street name, city, state, Pincode) => async (dispatch) => ..`?

Comment: @DreamBold yes the kind of json data i want to send is posted above

Comment: `) => async (dispatch) => {

  let data = {
    "userName": userName,
    "userPassword": userPassword,
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "phone": phone,
    "email": email,
    "aadharNo": aadharNo,
    "addressDTO":
        {
            "streetName": streetName,
            "city": city,
            "state": state,
            "pinCode": pincode
        }
}
  try {`